# Why is an input on a transparent div also being rendered transparent?

Tags: html, css

I have a transparent white div in which I want to place an input. For whatever reason, the input and button are also being rendered transparent.

HTML:

```
<div class="covered">
  <div class="container covered-container">
    <div class="col-md-12 infotron-home"><div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
        </div> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.covered{
  background: url(http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/140801145902-irpt-birds-heron-scott-baumann-horizontal-large-gallery.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80%;
  padding-top:50px
}
.covered-container{
  background-color:white;
  opacity: .7;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.infotron-home{
  margin-top:50px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Roboto Slab";
color:#0c5449;
}

.infotron-home li, .infotron-home p{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}


.search-home{
  width:80%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input, select, textarea{
  color: #ffffff !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49fp9ngk/1/

How can I make the input non-transparent and white like default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `opacity` is used on `parent element` it even effects it's `child elements`, so I suggest you to use `background` as `rgba` and remove `opacity` from both parent and child div, as below.

```css
div.covered{
  background: url(http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/140801145902-irpt-birds-heron-scott-baumann-horizontal-large-gallery.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80%;
  padding-top:50px;
}
.covered-container{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); /* Add this */
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.infotron-home{
margin-top:50px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Roboto Slab";
color:#0c5449;
}

.infotron-home li, .infotron-home p{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}

.search-home{
  width:80%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input, select, textarea{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,1); /* Add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="covered">
    <div class="container covered-container">
        <div class="col-md-12 infotron-home"><div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
     </div><!-- /input-group --> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.covered-container {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```